# Проблемы со звуком на Huawei matebook D16 на Arch Linux

Tags: linux, аудио, huawei

Поставил Arch Linux на  Huawei matebook D16 и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой - в настройках среди устройств выхода значится только одно аудиоустройство: Холостой выход (dummy output).
Прогуглил, в основном советуют решения типа
`sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/probe-fix.conf <<<'options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1'`
У меня это (и аналогичные) не работают.

Вывод aplay -l

```
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

p.s. нашел решение - поставить пропатченное ядро  https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-lts-huawei-amd-audio но не хотелось бы так радикально.

Comment: Ставь патченное ядро. Это проблема не только хуавеев. У многих ноутов новых нет звука без костылей даже в виндовс.